# Actions in OWL, modeling

Tags: owl, protege4

I have gone through this [guide](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-primer/#Appendix:_The_Complete_Sample_Ontology)  and I think that I understand it well. I understand that there are classes and instances of the classes and others.

Basically i have a many statements which I have to verify against an Ontology. For example: Eshtablish flag at "area" by 0600h.
Ex 2: Eshtablish fence between area1 and area2 by 0500h. and so I know for example area is an instance of  a class, but there can be so many areas. I know that 0500 is a data property of a thing, an area in particular.

The question is that I am unable to understand how to model actions like "Eshtablish" above into what of owl.

I am also assuming that i need  a reasoner to validate these real time statements(such as above) which come from the client against an ontology. Is this assumption true?

Another thing is that protege beta(latest) is unable to load ontologies, even the ones it own created, do you have this issue. I am going for older version.

Thanks

Comment: When you say unable to load ontologies - can you provide details?

Comment: When i click on "Open an Ontology" from file menu it is is saying in the cmd prompt "Loading the ontology" for indefinite time.

Comment: Is the ontology in a folder containing many other ontologies? Protege has a 'feature' that scans all ontologies in a folder if one is selected, to check for local copies of imports. For folders with large numbers of large ontologies, this can take time.

Comment: No no... Actually i made an ontology with only 2 classes and saved it... it was not even able to load that. Any way i switched to the older stable version and it is working. It has loaded the Pizza ontology. 

But my main question is something different