# copy an OWL Ontology in Jena

Tags: java, jena, semantic-web, owl, ontology

I am trying to copy an OWL ontology using Jena API, add a new statement to that ontology everytime. 
But at the beginning it should get the original ontology without the new statement.

The following code adds a new statement everytime, on top of the previous one.

```
this runs in a for loop{

        OntModel curOnto = onto1.getOntology();

        curOnto.add(s,p,o);

        /*printing the statement from onto1
        it seems it is adding new statement in onto1 on top of previous statement*/

        int lineNum = 0;
        for (StmtIterator i = onto1.getOntology().listStatements(); i.hasNext();) {
            Statement stmt = i.nextStatement();
            System.out.println( lineNum++ + " - " + PrintUtil.print(stmt));
        }
}
```

As suggested in other post I have tried to copy the ontology like this:

```
Model copyOnto = ModelFactory.createModelForGraph(onto1.getOntology().getGraph());
OntModel curOnto = new OntModelImpl(onto1.getOntology().getSpecification(), copyOnto);
```

but still the same, it keeps adding the new statement in onto1. 
I need to get a original copy of **onto1** in **curOnto** in each run of the for loop. Any help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, In protege you have an option to export the ontology to java code, did you not try?

Comment: Thanks for the info. But I need it in Runtime from source...

Comment: I am also new dear... My questions are also unanswered... looking for answers... Mine are more simple...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36741623/actions-in-owl-modeling?noredirect=1#comment61100964_36741623

Answer (score 1):

The suggestion above (using **org.apache.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory#createModelForGraph**) is wrong. All information is kept in the Graph. So you need copy whole graph (all triples). It can be done (for example) by method **org.apache.jena.graph.GraphUtil#addInto**